# red5 eclipse windows

Tags: red5

i have creted a new application on the logs i am getting this error. Anyone ?

[ERROR] 2009-11-04 11:00:12,458 WrapperSimpleAppMain:( org.mortbay.log.invoke0 ) Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@18baf36{/firstapp,file:/C:/Red5/webapps/firstapp/} 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/11/04 12:00:12 | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'web.scope' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/11/04 12:00:12 | PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [com.milgra.Application] to required type [org.red5.server.api.IScopeHandler] for property 'handler'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [com.milgra.Application] to required type [org.red5.server.api.IScopeHandler] for property 'handler': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/11/04 12:00:12 | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessException details (1) are:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/11/04 12:00:12 | PropertyAccessException 1:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/11/04 12:00:12 | org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [com.milgra.Application] to required type [org.red5.server.api.IScopeHandler] for property 'handler'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [com.milgra.Application] to required type [org.red5.server.api.IScopeHandler] for property 'handler': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/11/04 12:00:12 | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [com.milgra.Application] to required type [org.red5.server.api.IScopeHandler] for property 'handler': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/11/04 12:00:12 |   at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:231)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using both a really old version of Red5 (we have not defaulted to Jetty for quite some time) and an old Chat application ported from Milgra server.